# Edit existing content with powershell

Tags: powershell

I know it's a silly google question, but I didn't find something really simple for my need.

I have a .txt file with the following content:

```
hostname [ip] 
exec /bin/bash
```

Now, every time when I execute a certain PS script(from RUN) I want that [ip] will be changed according to my $args[0]

For example:

.txt now:

```
hostname 1.1.1.1 
exec /bin/bash
```

I am executing from run `script 2.2.2.2`

.txt expected:

```
hostname 2.2.2.2
exec /bin/bash
```

Note! The whole content will be always the same, only [ip] changes.

I am looking for the most simple replace solution, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite broad, and I don't want to write a whole script, so I will just answer the main part of it.

To replace "[ip]" in a file with "1.1.1.1":

```
gc input_file.txt | % { $_ -replace '\[ip\]', '1.1.1.1' } | sc output_file.txt
```

If you want to overwrite the original file, you need to put parentheses around the first statement so that it loads the entire file into memory at the beginning:

```
(gc my_file.txt) | % { $_ -replace '\[ip\]', '1.1.1.1' } | sc my_file.txt
```

`gc` is short for `Get-Content`, `sc` is `Set-Content`, and `%` is `ForEach-Object`.